# Sort list by nested tuple values

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

Is there a better way to sort a list by a nested tuple values than writing an itemgetter alternative that extracts the nested tuple value:

```
def deep_get(*idx):
  def g(t):
      for i in idx: t = t[i]
      return t
  return g

>>> l = [((2,1), 1),((1,3), 1),((3,6), 1),((4,5), 2)]
>>> sorted(l, key=deep_get(0,0))
[((1, 3), 1), ((2, 1), 1), ((3, 6), 1), ((4, 5), 2)]
>>> sorted(l, key=deep_get(0,1))
[((2, 1), 1), ((1, 3), 1), ((4, 5), 2), ((3, 6), 1)]
```

I thought about using compose, but that's not in the standard library:

```
sorted(l, key=compose(itemgetter(1), itemgetter(0))
```

Is there something I missed in the libs that would make this code nicer?

The implementation should work reasonably with 100k items.

Context: I would like to sort a dictionary of items that are a histogram. The keys are a tuples (a,b) and the value is the count. In the end the items should be sorted by count descending, a and b. An alternative is to flatten the tuple and use the itemgetter directly but this way a lot of tuples will be generated.

Comment: There's none that I'm aware of.  Your approach is nice as it is IMHO.

Comment: "The implementation should work reasonably with 100k items." -- this line is unnecessary; all implementations which use `sort` will work reasonably with 100k items

Comment: @ninjagecko The implementation will be different if you sort 3 items or 100k or 1T.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you could just use a `key=lambda x: x[0][1]`

Comment: Is `itemgetter(0)` faster than `lambda x: x[0]`? Have `compose(itemgetter(1), itemgetter(0))`, `lambda x: x[0][1]` and `deep_get` the same performance characteristics?

Comment: the lambda will almost certainly be faster than all of them, but it's all still `O(N log(N))` due to the sorting so I wouldn't worry too much about it; there are probably better things to optimize

Comment: I think itemgetter would be faster than lambda, because it's written in C. Why do you think lambda is faster?

Comment: @utdmr Everything goes through C, but you're still switching into python; you can only expect a speedup if most of your computation would be done in C and if C has some sort of major advantage by avoiding overhead. Furthermore **`compose` is implemented with a `lambda`** (same thing as a function, really) so you aren't saving anything. You're welcome to test this yourself. You fill find that the `compose` approach runs 50% slower. The `deep_get` however I would expect to run with roughly the same time (in fact it does). You can always use `dis.dis` to look at what the code compiles to.

Comment: The statement "`compose()` is implemented with a `lambda`" is somewhat strange.  How do you know?  My version of `compose()` might be written as a C extension...

Comment: @Sven I see you are playing devil's-advocate =) if you were implementing everything in C, you might as well write everything in C, and assuming you are still writing the program in python, you still have the "overhead" of interfacing with the python calling-convention in C. You are welcome to implement your own `compose` as a C module to see if it is faster; in fact I would be curious if it would have any effect. Nevertheless I feel that people optimize too much in the wrong places, that design decisions account for more, and that programmer time is more valuable than minor optimizations.

Comment: @ninjagecko: My point was rather that you simply don't know how `compose()` is implemented since it's not a standard function.  Usually, I'd implement it [like this](https://gist.github.com/997063), which is without a lambda.  Of course your reasoning would still be valid for this implementation. :)

Comment: @Sven yes, this is why I said "(same thing as a function, really)" to preempt this discussion =) because `types.FunctionType==types.LambdaType`, and `def f(x):return x; dis.dis(f)` and `dis.dis(lambda x:x)` yield the same opcodes (also if you call them with `*args,**kw`.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is quite good, given the data structure that you have.

Another approach would be to use another structure.

If you want speed, the de-factor standard [NumPy](https://numpy.org) is the way to go.  Its job is to efficiently handle large arrays.  It even has some nice sorting routines for arrays like yours.  Here is how you would write your sort over the counts, and then over (a, b):

```
>>> arr = numpy.array([((2,1), 1),((1,3), 1),((3,6), 1),((4,5), 2)],
                  dtype=[('pos', [('a', int), ('b', int)]), ('count', int)])
>>> print numpy.sort(arr, order=['count', 'pos'])
[((1, 3), 1) ((2, 1), 1) ((3, 6), 1) ((4, 5), 2)]
```

This is very fast (it's implemented in C).

If you want to stick with standard Python, a list containing (count, a, b) tuples would automatically get sorted in the way you want by Python (which uses lexicographic order on tuples).

Answer (score 1):

I compared two similar solutions. The first one uses a simple lambda:

```
def sort_one(d):
    result = d.items()
    result.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
    return result
```

Note the minus on `x[1]`, because you want the sort to be descending on count.

The second one takes advantage of the fact that `sort` in Python is stable. First, we sort by `(a, b)` (ascending). Then we sort by count, descending:

```
def sort_two(d):
    result = d.items()
    result.sort()
    result.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return result
```

The first one is 10-20% faster (both on small and large datasets), and both complete under 0.5sec on my Q6600 (one core used) for 100k items. So avoiding the creation of tuples doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little faster version of your approach:

```
l = [((2,1), 1), ((1,3), 1), ((3,6), 1), ((4,5), 2)]

def deep_get(*idx):
    def g(t):
        return reduce(lambda t, i: t[i], idx, t)
    return g

>>> sorted(l, key=deep_get(0,1))
[((2, 1), 1), ((1, 3), 1), ((4, 5), 2), ((3, 6), 1)]
```

Which could be shortened to:

```
def deep_get(*idx):
    return lambda t: reduce(lambda t, i: t[i], idx, t)
```

or even just simply written-out:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda t: reduce(lambda t, i: t[i], (0,1), t))
```